Why when i click on an image it doesent triger the event listener? (VanillaJS)
I try to make a script that can harvest some data of me playing rock paper scissors on a site (https://www.rpsgame.org/):
var h_choice = document.querySelectorAll(".play-page-gamer__choices")[0];
var h_rock = document.querySelectorAll(".play-page-gamer__choices")[0]
    .childNodes[1].childNodes[2];
var h_paper = document.querySelectorAll(".play-page-gamer__choices")[0]
    .childNodes[3].childNodes[2];
var h_scissors = document.querySelectorAll(".play-page-gamer__choices")[0]
    .childNodes[5].childNodes[2];

game = [];

h_rock.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("rock");
});
h_paper.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("paper");
});
h_scissors.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("scissors");
});

btw that not all the code but it's the important part of this problem if you want all of it just ask 
so I set up event so i can know what choice i make by using events but there not trigered when i click on the image
when I click on an image I expect to have a message in the console like paper if I click on paper but nothing appears
but when I simulate a click like this
h_paper.click() it return paper in the console
I even verify if the eventListener was not removed but not beceause when I type h_paper.eventListeners it return an array with in my function which is:
() => {
    console.log('paper')
}


Please use the HTML/JS snippets feature to make a [mcve] showcasing your issue.

If you're only interested in the first match of a selector, use document.querySelector(selector) rather than document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0].

The elements are refreshed, and the event listeners are removed - at least that's what I see when looking at the site you provided. You need to go higher up in the DOM, until you find a stable ancestor. Then, attach your click event listener to it, and check what the event.target is. If it matches one of the three elements you're after (rock, paper, scissors holder), log it to the console.

I found the solution, so when I clicked on the image, I instead clicked on the div tag as the parent element. so that's it.
the update version is on: https://github.com/Ryn-Bghl/RPS_analysis/blob/main/scripts/csv_generator.js
